# To select the newest 3 questions from PostgreSQL by PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

**How can you select the titles of the newest 3 questions from PostgreSQL database by PHP?**

### **My attempt in PHP**

```
$result = pg_prepare($dbconn, "query1", "SELECT title FROM 
    questions ORDER BY was_sent_at_time 
    WHERE question_id = $1;");
$result = pg_execute($dbconn, "query1", array(7, 1, 9);     
   // Problem HERE, since I do not know how you can get the 3 newest questions
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MySQL it would look something like

```
SELECT title FROM questions ORDER BY was_sent_at_time DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Not sure if it still applies without changes to Postgres.

Comment: Yes, PostgreSQL, MySQL, and SQLite support the LIMIT clause, though this syntax is not part of the SQL standard.

Answer (score 2):

Change your query to:

```
"SELECT title FROM questions WHERE question_id = $1 
ORDER BY was_sent_at_time DESC LIMIT 3;"
```